# what causes this error NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, firefox

I'm using URLLoader in flex, but as i load a certain url, the connection is aborted (monitored using HTTPFox plugin in firefox). I simulate same instance on another server but it does not abort. When I checked HTTPFox content it has the following value:

**Error loading content (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED)**

I've been searching the net but there seemed to be no explaination why NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED occurs. I just  thought knowing why such error message appeared would solve why the connection is aborted.

Here is a part of the code of the sample i made to test on both of the servers that worked and did not that does the URLLoader.

```
private var UrlLoaderService : URLLoader = new URLLoader();

function initializeData():void
{
     var parameters : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
     var requests : URLRequest = new URLRequest();

     parameters.param1="param1";
     parameters.param2="param2";
     parameters.param3="param3";

     requests.data = parameters;
     requests.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
     requests.url = "/sampletest/testrequest.php?antiCache="+Math.random();

     UrlLoaderService.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, successResult);
     UrlLoaderService.load(requests);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context?  Can you show some code?  If it works on one server, but not another it sounds like it may be an issue with the server setup.

Comment: Looks like most google results for NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED are related to httpfox setup, so i suggest its a red herring (at least as far as  solving URLLoader problem).

Comment: Thanx for the responses, i did some google searches as well. But if it really is due to httpfox then how come it was not aborted on the other server?
I was thinking about server set up might be causing but not quite sure since I dont know what NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED means, or on what instance does it appear.